# XNA Game with MonoGame on Mac

Tags: macos, xna, monogame

I have just moved over to a mac and I am continuing my development with XNA using monogame.

However when I am trying to use `Gamepad.GetState(index)` and it is throwing the following error.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tao.Sdl, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c7a200e36c0094e' or one of its dependencies.
>         at at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.GamePad.GetState (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.PlayerIndex) 
>         at MultiverseRPG.InputHandler..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game) [0x00063] in /Users/aaron.wheeler/Projects/MultiverseRPG/MultiverseRPG/xna/InputHandler.cs:94
>         at MultiverseRPG.Game1..ctor () [0x00068] in /Users/aaron.wheeler/Projects/MultiverseRPG/MultiverseRPG/Game1.cs:62
>         at MultiverseRPG.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) [0x00002] in /Users/aaron.wheeler/Projects/MultiverseRPG/MultiverseRPG/Main.cs:35
>         at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.[MultiverseRPG.AppDelegate.Void FinishedLaunching(MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)] (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) 
>         at at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.[MultiverseRPG.AppDelegate.Void FinishedLaunching(MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject)] (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject,MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector,MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject) 
>         at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.NSApplicationMain (int,string[]) <0x00012>
>         at at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Main (string[]) 
>         at MultiverseRPG.Program.Main (string[]) [0x0001d] in /Users/aaron.wheeler/Projects/MultiverseRPG/MultiverseRPG/Main.cs:22

Comment: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tao.Sdl, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c7a200e36c0094e' or one of its dependencies.` Did you check if you have that file around?

Comment: What part of _"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: **Could not load file or assembly 'Tao.Sdl**, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c7a200e36c0094e' **or one of its dependencies**"_ don't you understand?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. How would I make sure these are included in my project on mac. Luckily this just all works on PC which I am use to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by adding the Tao.sdl.dll file to the project and adding in a .net reference for the project.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you got it going :)

Comment: Yer I have been dealing with a few problems since moving over to the mac :) but getting there.